# How to change Iron's default 404 behaviour?

Tags: rust, iron

I want to change the default 404 behaviour in a small Iron application. I want to add some simple text content to it, nothing complicated like using templates.

Answer (score 1):

Iron [has an example for how to do this](https://github.com/iron/router/blob/master/examples/custom_404.rs).

Create and start your program on an `iron::Chain`, and then create an `iron::middleware::AfterMiddleware`. This middleware could look like:

```
fn custom_404(req: &mut Request, res: &mut Response) -> IronResult<Response> {
    if response.status == Some(Status::NotFound) {
        // Create a response as desired here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding this to `iron::middleware::AfterMiddleware` is sufficient to make it the default?

Comment: @YvesDorfsman Adding that as an aftermiddleware to the chain your website is mounted on would be, as all responses would go through it before being sent out. You're looking for iron::middleware::Chain::link_after I believe